# ColdFusion 9 Cluster on VMWare

Tags: vmware-esx, coldfusion

We're running several VMWare VM's and we have a strange behavior with a ColdFusion 9 cluster.

When the VMs are running on the same ESX, the sessions are shared between the different instances. When the VMs are on two different ESXs the session are not shared anymore.

Do you have any idea?

Is there anybody running this kind of configuration without any problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your servers can see eachother on the network?  Chances are that if your servers worked on the same ESX, but not on seperate ESX servers, your servers can't see eachother on the network.

Comment: I've got some new understanding on our issue.
In fact the VMs have 3 network interfaces. There is only one interface allowing multicast communication.
I don't know how to configure jRun underlaying ColdFusion to communicate on a choosen interface. We've understood that jRun communicate on the last interface mounted by the system (RedHat). Is there a way to configure the IP multicast used by jRun?

Comment: By the way, we can't use unicast as proposed discussed [here](http://www.webmasterkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/coldfusion-server/3392/CF8-JRun4-Cluster-for-Load-Balancing) because we have 3 instances of ColdFusion part of 3 different clusters...

Comment: Would you happen to be using VCenter?